# ':app:processDebugManifest' error while importing project

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to import an Android sample project then i get this message error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0] C:\Users\HP.android\build-cache\084ac0ca1bed4f5e30644d43f2b1fe5758c0d427\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage

Comment: change min sdk to 14

Comment: there is a **Suggestion** in error: `use tools:overrideLibrary = "com.google.android.gms.play_services"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change min sdk to 14 in build.gradle file of app module.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, libraries have their own `minSdkVersion`. When you add a library in your project, which here is `gms.play_services`, for example, uses `14` as `minSdkVersion`, and in the meantime, you are using `10` in your own project, this error will appear while you're trying to sync your project. SO:

- Or you have to raise your projects `minSdkVersion` to `14`.
- Or you can add `tools:overrideLibrary` in your `manifest` like this:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <uses-sdk
      tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services"/>

  </manifest>
  ```